# Is there a built-in function to copy a directory in Dart?

Tags: directory, copy, dart

Is there a built-in function to copy a directory and recursively copy all the files (and other directories) in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not to my knowledge there isn't. But Dart supports basic reading and writing of files from directories, so it stands to reason that this could be solved programmatically.

Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Swader/5163867) I found of a tool that would accomplish this process.

Basically, you would search the directory for files you wanted to copy and perform the copy operation:

```
newFile.writeAsBytesSync(element.readAsBytesSync());
```

to all file paths, `new Path(element.path);`, in the `new Directory(newLocation);`.

**Edit:**

But this is super inefficient, because the whole files has to be read in by the system and wrote back out to a file. You could just [use a shell process](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8148) spawned by Dart to take care of the process for you:

```
Process.run("cmd", ["/c", "copy", ...])
```

Answer (score 6):

Found https://pub.dev/documentation/io/latest/io/copyPath.html (or the sync version of same) which seems to be working for me. It's part of the io package https://pub.dev/documentation/io/latest/io/io-library.html available at https://pub.dev/packages/io.

It does the equivalent of `cp -R <from> <to>`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you James, wrote a quick function for it, but did it an alternative way. I'm unsure if this way would be anymore efficient or not?

```dart
/**
 * Retrieve all files within a directory
 */
Future<List<File>> allDirectoryFiles(String directory)
{
  List<File> frameworkFilePaths = [];

  // Grab all paths in directory
  return new Directory(directory).list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
  .listen((FileSystemEntity entity)
  {
    // For each path, if the path leads to a file, then add to array list
    File file = new File(entity.path);
    file.exists().then((exists)
    {
      if (exists)
      {
        frameworkFilePaths.add(file);
      }
    });

  }).asFuture().then((_) { return frameworkFilePaths; });

}
```

Edit: OR! An even better approach (in some situations) would be to return a stream of files in the directory:

```dart
/**
 * Directory file stream
 *
 * Retrieve all files within a directory as a file stream.
 */
Stream<File> _directoryFileStream(Directory directory)
{
  StreamController<File> controller;
  StreamSubscription source;

  controller = new StreamController<File>(
    onListen: ()
    {
      // Grab all paths in directory
      source = directory.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false).listen((FileSystemEntity entity)
      {
        // For each path, if the path leads to a file, then add the file to the stream
        File file = new File(entity.path);
        file.exists().then((bool exists)
        {
          if (exists)
            controller.add(file);
        });
      },
      onError: () => controller.addError,
      onDone: () => controller.close
      );
    },
    onPause: () { if (source != null) source.pause(); },
    onResume: () { if (source != null) source.resume(); },
    onCancel: () { if (source != null) source.cancel(); }
  );

  return controller.stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

void copyDirectorySync(Directory source, Directory destination) {
  /// create destination folder if not exist
  if (!destination.existsSync()) {
    destination.createSync(recursive: true);
  }
  /// get all files from source (recursive: false is important here)
  source.listSync(recursive: false).forEach((entity) {
    final newPath = destination.path + Platform.pathSeparator + path.basename(entity.path);
    if (entity is File) {
      entity.copySync(newPath);
    } else if (entity is Directory) {
      copyDirectorySync(entity, Directory(newPath));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works well, why no one upvotes :D. Use this one if you don't want to import `final newPath = destination.path + Platform.pathSeparator + entity.path.split(Platform.pathSeparator).last;`

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today.
Turns out the io package from pub.dev solve this in a clean api:
copyPath or copyPathSync

https://pub.dev/documentation/io/latest/io/copyPath.html